# NFSe - Padrão São Paulo e Blumenau, problema com erro 1057 e assinatura?

Tags: xml, nfe, assinatura-digital

Vamos por partes.

Primeiro, testei já o EnvioRPS e o EnvioLoteRPS e ambos retornam o mesmo erro:

```
[1057] Rejeição - Assinatura difere do calculado.
```

Estou formando o XML e está ficando desta forma:

https://pastebin.com/NBXtXN0m

Estou usando a biblioteca do NFE PHP SPED para assinar o XML

https://github.com/nfephp-org/nfephp

Usando APENAS para assinar o XML, da seguinte forma:

```
    $certificate = Certificate::readPfx(file_get_contents($cert_path.'cert.pfx'), '1234');
    $xml_signed = Signer::sign($certificate, $xml_signed,
        'PedidoEnvioLoteRPS', // Tag à ser assinada
        null,
        OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1    // Algorithm
    );
```

E usando este XML, assinado, para envio ao WebService.

Já recebi o erro 1056 e 1057, ambos referentes à assinatura e digest.

Alguém tem um arquivo de exemplo de geração desta NFSe, assinando-a usando o PFX (A1)?

Alguém pode me ajudar com esta questão?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

acabei de ter o mesmo problema.
troca isso:

```
$xml_signed = Signer::sign($certificate, $xml_signed,
        'PedidoEnvioLoteRPS', // Tag à ser assinada
        null,
        OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1    // Algorithm
    );
```

por isso:

```
  $canonical = [false,false,null,null];
    $xml_signed = Signer::sign($certificate, $xml_signed,
    'PedidoEnvioLoteRPS', 
    '', 
    OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1,
    $canonical,
    '');
```